# using goto vs while(wrongchoice) with a switch.

Tags: goto

I was wondering if there's a reason why you should not use a goto vs use a while(variable) in this case :

```
:start
result=askUser("do you want 1,2,or 3?")
switch(result){
   case 1: display("you chose 1")
   case 2: display("you chose 2")
   case 3: display("you chose 3")
   default: display("choice not availaible")
            goto :start 
}
```

vs

```
boolean wrongchoice=false
do
result=askUser("do you want 1,2,or 3?")
switch(result){
   case 1: display("you chose 1")
   case 2: display("you chose 2")
   case 3: display("you chose 3")
   default: display("choice not availaible")
            wrongchoice=true
}
while(wrongchoice)
```

it seems to me that goto would be better on a small µc because you avoid having to set a variable and use memory for it (when you only have 256, a bit is a bit)

for today's computers, being greedy for a few bits is futile though, so is using the while much more clear then?

Answer (score 1):

> for today's computers, being greedy for a few bits is futile though, so is using the while much more clear then?

Exactly. Readability & maintainability is more important than performance in an overwhelming number of cases.

I've encountered situation where `goto` was faster than a while loop even with -O3 optimization, but this was in the innermost loop of an O(n^2) algorithm of a molecular dynamics simulator. Barring intense use cases  (which require more intensive maintenance over the life of the code!), use the `while` because it's more readable and is less likely to do weird things.

Comment: I actually had a use case for this a few days ago, but on a 16mhz uc controlling a cnc, in an interrupt block where shaving 1-2 instructions meant I could have a faster feed rate (well, a 2% increase.).